# How to check that a SOAP response is empty?

Tags: soap, soapui

I have a couple of SoapUI test steps in which the responses come back empty (i.e. "-> null/empty response"), which is what I expect.

How can I assert that a response to a test step's request is empty?

So far I have tried the following with no luck:

- Reviewed available assertions for a fit without customization - e.g. an "Empty Response" assertion much like the SOAP Response assertion: none seems to exist.
- Used a Not Contains regex assertion on `.+`: it failed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ended up using a Script Assertion with `assert messageExchange.hasResponse() == false` in it, which seems to work.  If there is a better way to assert the condition, I would be interested to learn it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved similar problem in this way:

```
response = context.testCase.testSteps['test step name'].testRequest.response
assert response == null
```